# How to have multiple cluster in kafka by using docker?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I'm trying to up multiple clusters with three nodes in kafka with using docker and I followed this approach in my docker-compose file but this is wrong and I can't up Kafka those I wrote in my docker-compose file
please tell me the true docker-compose file or true approach for that to up multiple clusters (with three nodes) in Kafka by using docker

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22101
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS:      localhost:22000:23000;localhost:32000:33000;localhost:42000:43000
    network_mode: host
      extra_hosts:
        - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 42181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888
    network_mode: host
    extra_hosts:
      - "moby:127.0.0.1"

kafka-1:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
  network_mode: host
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper-1
    - zookeeper-2
    - zookeeper-3
  environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092
kafka-2:
   image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
   network_mode: host
   depends_on:
     - zookeeper-1
     - zookeeper-2
     - zookeeper-3
   environment:
   KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENER: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
 extra_hosts:
   - "moby:127.0.0.1"
kafka-3:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
  network_mode: host
  depends_on:
    - zookeeper-1
    - zookeeper-2
    - zookeeper-3
  environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092
extra_hosts:
  - "moby:127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by following this link:

https://github.com/conduktor/kafka-stack-docker-compose

my question was about how can I have multiple nodes in Kafka  by using docker-compose
and I used this Item : Single Zookeeper / Multiple Kafka , from  that repository and ran this command to use it:

```
docker-compose -f zk-single-Kafka-single.yml up
```

and after that , you can use this command for checking which containers are up:

```
sudo docker ps
```

and name of outputs are:

kafka-stack-docker-compose_kafka2_1

kafka-stack-docker-compose_kafka3_1

kafka-stack-docker-compose_kafka1_1

zoo1

with their ID and STATUS and ...

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration is wrong:
Each zk node has a process (named QuorumPeerMain) which listen to clients on a default port **2181** and communicate with each other on port **2888:3888**. So when try to define a zookeeper quorum define it as `zk1:[port],zk2:[port],...`

```
 zookeeper-1:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
...
...
 zookeeper-2:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
...
...
 zookeeper-3:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
```

and in Kafka properties:

```
KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,zookeeper-3:2181
```

Follow this link: [Guide to Setting Up Apache Kafka Using Docker](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/kafka-docker-setup)

Comment: The Zookeeper properties are fine. They are all overridden because `network_mode: host` is set